# Changing the color of the block using the calculator package

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I'm trying to plot blocks with different colors. but it looks like all of them are getting the same color and only the last block is changing its color.

What went wrong in this code

```
   \documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
     \usepackage{calculator}
     \usepackage{calculus}
     \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\def\M{2}
        \foreach \i in {0.2,0.4,...,1}
        { 
        \MULTIPLY{\i}{20}{\c};
         \draw[fill=blue!\c,opacity=0.75] % transverse plane
        ({-0.2*\M}, {-1.1*\M}) rectangle ($({0.1*\M}, {-1.1*\M})+(0,\i*\M)$);    
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: For one, your code doesn't compile because `\M` is not defined. And other errors.

Comment: Still several errors. Try compiling your code first...

Comment: I fixed them and I compiled it

Comment: Well okay. However it does work as intended namely that the latter-drawn square is bolder. More likely the coordinate calculation is wrong, but we don't know what you intend to calculate/draw.

Comment: Indeed, “it works” but we don't know what Diana wants. The rectangle can be described more simply with `(-0.2*\M, -1.1*\M) rectangle (0.1*\M, -1.1*\M + \i*\M)`—there is no need for `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` (`\usepackage{calculus}` is also useless here). Warnings are caused by the `;` at the end of the `\MULTIPLY` line: this is not a Ti*k*Z nor `pgfplots` statement; it should be removed.

Comment: It is maybe easier to differentiate the shades with `opacity=0.25`.

Comment: It is strange though that using the MWE and changing the draw command to `\draw[fill=blue,opacity=0.25]` you get five different _colors_ while it is expected to get the same shade of blue each time.

Comment: @Marijn The lowest *visible rectangle* is filled 5 times, the 2nd lower 4 times, the third lower 3 times, etc. and the upper *visible* rectangle only once. Isn't it expected that the partial opacity somehow “adds up”? (The actually drawn `rectangle`s overlap.)

Comment: @frougon I see, from the code I didn't realize that the rectangle had the same starting point but was increasing in height (although that is obvious when I look at the code again), I thought it was a series of small, same-size, non-overlapping rectangles.

Answer (score 2):

The rectangle can be described more simply with `(-0.2*\M, -1.1*\M) rectangle (0.1*\M, -1.1*\M + \i*\M)`—there is no need for `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` here, and also not for `\usepackage{calculus}`. Warnings are caused by the `;` at the end of the `\MULTIPLY` line: this is not a Ti*k*Z nor `pgfplots` statement; this semicolon should be removed.

Your main problem is possibly that your coordinate computations don't correspond to what you really want? Here is an idea:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\uM{2}
  \def\mycolors{{"blue","orange","green","magenta","cyan"}}

  \foreach \i[count=\idx starting from 0] in {0.2,0.4,...,1}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\mycolors[\idx]}
      \path[fill=\mycolor, opacity=0.5]
        (-0.2*\uM, -1.1*\uM + \i*\uM) rectangle +(0.3*\uM, 0.2*\uM);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]